# Global save, detect and prevent changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have tabs application, each Tab contain many views... And in each Tab the save mode is global.
If I leave current tab containing changes, a pop-up appear asking user confirm with or without save or cancel. After save, others opened tabs is reloaded.
How would you do, to detect the changes? To save only the views changed? And then to propagate the changes to the other tabs?
My first think is, to implement a IsModified property and ReloadTab method in each ViewModel, but is not really viable solution, each setter must change this property... Any idea ?

```
class MyViewMode 
{
    ...
    public bool IsModified { get { return MyViewModel1.IsModified || MyViewModel2.IsModified ... || _isModified }
    ...
}
```

[EDIT]

I hesitate between EventAggregator approach and Messenger (MVVM Light Toolkit implementation)...

I think I am going to create Events/Messages Domain representing each command generates a tab reloading, and create a Handler (Service receive all messages/events and send specific messages/events for each View to be reloaded). Any advices ?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this using a global event broker. The idea is that events such as save which have global scope will pass through this broker class.

The event broker is a singleton, where each class will register it's handlers. The handler would be registered using attributes:

```
[EventSubscribe(EventNames.Save)]
private void OnSaved(GlobalEventArgs args)
{
    // do something on saved
}
```

And each object that wishes to push itself to the broker would do it like this:

```
EventBroker.Instance.Register(this);
```

How does this relate to your tabs issue? Fairly simply, when one tab saves, then that should raise the *save* event via the EventBroker:

```
    EventBroker.Instance.Publish(
        EventNames.Save, 
        new SavedGlobalEventArgs(typeof(YourModel)));
```

And all your other tabs would handle the event such as this:

```
    [EventSubscribe(EventNames.Save)]
    private void OnSaved(GlobalEventArgs args)
    {
        var savedArgs = (SavedGlobalEventArgs)args;

        if(savedArgs.SavedType == typeof(YourModel)
        {
             this.Model.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

You'll still have to handle the saved event on each tab that *might* require a refresh when another tab has done something, but this keeps the code relatively nice and simple without having to put all kinds of crap in. Can also extend it outside of a save event, make some other global events that may be useful:

UserCreated
UserLoggedIn
SearchInitiated

whatever; i don't know the context of your app - but the broker is a really nice way to deal with sharing knowledge in a tabbed environment.

Please let me know if you want me to send some code :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, what about Event Broker implementation in Unity ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by modifying each setter. If not, you cannot know exactly if your model data has changed and I wouldn't suggest tracking modified changes in the UI. Something like this should give you a good head start.

```
public class Person : IModifiable
{
    private bool _markDirty;

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Name)
                _markDirty = true;
            _Name = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsDirty()
    {
        return _markDirty;
    }
}

public interface IModifiable
{
    public bool IsDirty();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your repsponse, I do not need to know if my Entity has changed but rather an entire tab

Comment: This was only a concept. I don't know if your whole tab is bound to one class or many, but the idea is clear. You need to keep track of changes in your model per tab.